# Copy Constructor Error: returning a value from a constructor

Tags: c++, compiler-errors, copy-constructor, deep-copy

I may have just done something stupid but I can't find the answer to this error message anywhere.

The problem I'm having is I keep getting the error
"returning a value from a constructor"

My code here is a copy constructor:

```
RealBox::RealBox(const RealBox& rhs)
{
  if(this != &rhs)
  {
    m_boxsize = rhs.m_boxsize;
    delete[] m_reals;
    m_reals = new float [m_boxsize];

    for(int i=0;i<m_boxsize;i++)
    {
      m_reals[i]=rhs.m_reals[i];
    }
  }
  return *this;
}
```

From a class:

```
class RealBox
{ 
  private:  
    float* m_reals;                     // Array of Real Numbers
    int m_boxsize;                      // number of Real Numbers    


public:
  RealBox(int s, float a);
  ~RealBox();
  const RealBox& operator=(const RealBox& rhs);

  // Purpose: Copy Constructor
  // Parameters: rhs - RealBox to be copied
  // Postconditions:  *this == rhs
  RealBox(const RealBox& rhs);

  void set( int i, float x);
  friend std::ostream& operator<< (std::ostream& out, 
                               const RealBox& box);
};
```

I'm sure I've just done something stupid but I can't figure it out, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Literally, returning a value from a constructor is not allowed.

Comment: What part of the error message didn't you understand?

Comment: Maybe you're thinking of a different language, like C?

Comment: yeah, I just figured out what was happening (I also had to delete, delete) I'm sorry I'm such a noob

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get rid of `return *this;` from your copy constructor.

PS - I don't think it is valid for a copy constructor to ever be passed a reference to `*this` and so you don't have to protect against it.  If it were somehow to occur, either the passed argument to be copied from is itself not constructed, or you are re-constructing an already constructed object.  Either way it's wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Do not return in a copy ctor.

`return *this;`is error.

I think that you take the **assignment operator** and **copy constructor** function confused.